# Is there a better way than int( byte_buffer.encode('hex'), 16 )

Tags: python, integer, types, byte

In Python, I'm constantly using the following sequence to get an integer value from a byte buffer (in python this is a str).

I'm getting the buffer from the struct.unpack() routine.  When I unpack a 'char' using

```
byte_buffer, = struct.unpack('c', raw_buffer)
int_value = int( byte_buffer.encode('hex'), 16 )
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need the byte buffer as a python integer?

Comment: I'm typically pulling the value out of binary packet stream.

Comment: So is the integer value bounded or unbounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bounded to 1 byte – Noah Campbell 18 mins ago

The best way to do this then is to instantiate a struct unpacker.

```
from struct import Struct

unpacker = Struct("b")
unpacker.unpack("z")[0]
```

Note that you can change "b" to "B" if you want an unsigned byte. Also, endian format is not needed.

For anyone else who wants to know a method for unbounded integers, create a question, and tell me in the comments.

Comment: Ahh...using the b vs. B returns an integer.  (Flips to the python docs and realizes he needed to keep reading...)

Answer (score 6):

The [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct) module is good at unpacking binary data.

```
int_value = struct.unpack('>I', byte_buffer)[0]
```

Comment: Noah didn't specify that the number will always be from 0 to unsigned int.

Comment: @nosklo, no, the code he pasted accepts unbounded integers. Try int( ("a"*500).encode('hex'), 16 ) for proof.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about getting the integer value of a byte, then you want this:

```
ord(byte_buffer)
```

Can't understand why it isn't already suggested.

Comment: Perhaps because struct is more likely to be the correct answer for other parts of his problem, if reading various pieces of data from a byte stream.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but the asker didn't specify whether or not it would be signed or unsigned, so struct is the best option.